# How do I turn off the "Contribution amounts section" for a membership only contribution page?

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, civimember

Using 4.7.18 and Wordpress 4.7.4, on my contribution page that I want to configure as a membership only sign-up page, I untick the checkbox labelled "Contribution Amounts section enabled" on the 'Amounts' tab of the contribution page set-up wizard. However, after saving the page, if i then go pack in I see that this field is once again ticked.

I've just repeated this on http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org and got the same result. It looks like this is a bug.

Update: now logged as an issue here: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20495

Answer (score 1):

I see the same thing on Drupal/CiviCRM 4.7.18 - but it looks like the checkbox only gets checked again -> when you go into the Config. That is you can still uncheck it and Save it and have a Membership only Contribution form with no additional amounts. For some reason it defaults to ON now on edit of the contribution form config. Definitively a bug - and a regression [this was for sure working previously].

[image]

Comment: In my case what I saw was that although there was no field for additional amounts as you say Karin, there was a 'total amount' label on the page that doesn't make sense. I can hide it with CSS, but that's an irritation I can do without.

Comment: I don't see an additional amounts - see screenshot - also on 4.7.18 - it would be annoying to have to get rid of them with CSS

Comment: Transpires I'm seeing the "total amount" label because the developer that set up the CSS made an error! What is it it about a class called .hiddenElement that's so hard to understand?

Comment: A phew! I like it when mysteries get solved. If you log a JIRA for this - point me to it and I'll mark it verified.

Comment: JIRA link added to the question.